# Is there "bitsadmin" for jobs that use Delivery Optimization?

Tags: windows-update, bits

Download jobs under the BITS service are easy to administer via bitsadmin.

Is there ANY way how to remove Download jobs under the new DO (Delivery Optimization) service?

Jobs can be listed by PS>GetDeliveryOptimizationStatus, but I found no way how to selectively remove jobs from the queue. There was an article about deleting the files that hold the queue, but I can't find it anymore.

PS: SF seems to have no tag for "DO", "DOSVC", "WUDO" or "Delivery Optimization"

Comment: Update: By luck, running "wsreset" got rid of them. All offending jobs belonged to windows store I guess.

Comment: You can post your own solutions as an answer (rather than a comment) and (as a new user after a delay) even accept that answer marking your question as “resolved”   .

Comment: I know. I do not consider my comment to be the answer. Yes, i accidentally got rid of the offending jobs. No, wsreset cannot be used to manage DO jobs.